# VUE - [food toppings counter ] how increase value of element -topping- in a v-for list -of toppings- when click on "+ add" button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a beginner in js and vue and I'm building a website to automate the orders of my pizzeria delivery.

I have a v-for list of toppings, customers can choose up to 4 toppings from a list and he can select 2, 3 or 4 times the same topping.

I created a counter for each item in the list, which stores the selected topping name in an array with a limit of 4. This worked.

How can I select and increase the amount of topping selected in the interface?

Below I have my code, and some visual references

https://codepen.io/mordzin/pen/VwePBzq

```
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    flavorCounter: 0,
    cardapio: [],
    order: [],
    selectedItem: null
  },
  mounted() {
        // const axios = require('axios');
        axios.get('https://v2-api.sheety.co/4a5e4bb41d15a6ea344152fafca024db/zunepizza/cardapio')
        .then((response) => {

          this.cardapio = response.data.cardapio
        })
        .catch((error) => {

        })
        .finally(() => {

        })
      },

      methods:{

        addFlavor(){

          if (this.flavorCounter <= 3) {
            flavor = event.target.getAttribute('flavor')
            this.order.push(flavor);
            this.flavorCounter ++

            console.log(this.order)
            console.log(this.flavorCounter)
          } else {
            console.log('Maximo de sabores')
          }
        },

        removeFlavor(){

            if (this.flavorCounter >= 1) {
            flavor = event.target.getAttribute('flavor')

            this.order.splice(index, 1);
            this.flavorCounter --

            console.log(this.order)
            console.log(this.flavorCounter)
          } else {
          }
        },

      }


    });
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
    <title>Zune Pizza</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="zunepizza.css">
    <link async href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link async href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <template>
            <div id="cardapio">
                <ul v-for="cardapio in cardapio">
                    <li>
                     <div class="item-info">
                        <h3 class="item-title">{{cardapio.name}}</h3>
                        <div class="tag">
                            <h5>{{cardapio.type}}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <p class="item-title">{{cardapio.desc}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <div class="flavorCounter" :id="cardapio.name">
                            <button
                            @click="addFlavor()"
                            :flavor="cardapio.name"
                            class="addFlavor controller-btn"> + </button>

                            <input :id='cardapio.name' type="number" value="0" class="flavorQuantity">

                            <button
                            @click='removecliFlavor()'
                            :flavor='cardapio.name'
                            class="addFlavor controller-btn"> - </button>
                        </div>
                       <img src="img/cardapio/baska.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </template>

</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="zunepizza.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[zune pizza interface topping counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1zMk.png)

i need something like the image below

[ifood interface topping counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vf0d.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding an `amount` property (for example) to your items:

```js
this.cardapio = response.data.cardapio.map(data => ({ ...data, amount: 0 }))
```

Then you can bind the `amount` to the elements in your markup and modify it:

```
<!--It is always good to assign an :key-->
<ul v-for="(item, i) in cardapio" :key="i">
  ...
  <button @click="item.amount < 4 ? item.amount++ : ''" ... > + </button> 
  <input v-model="item.amount"...>
  <button @click="item.amount > 0 ? item.amount-- : ''" ... > + </button>
  ...
</ul>
```

To find selected items, you can just filter items with `amount` >0:

```js
this.order = this.cardapio.filter(({ amount }) => amount > 0);
```

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 1):

you can do smth like this: https://codepen.io/jasik/pen/NWxdLRg

```
<div id="cardapio">
    <ul v-for="cardapio in cardapios">
      <li>
        <div class="item-info">
          <h3 class="item-title">{{cardapio.name}}</h3>
          <div class="tag">
            <h5>{{cardapio.type}}</h5>
          </div>
          <p class="item-title">{{cardapio.desc}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-img">
          <div class="flavorCounter" :id="cardapio.name">
            <button @click="cardapio.counter++" :disabled="cardapio.counter === 4" :flavor="cardapio.name" class="addFlavor controller-btn"> + </button>

            <input :id='cardapio.name' type="number" v-model="cardapio.counter" class="flavorQuantity">

            <button @click='cardapio.counter--' :disabled="cardapio.counter === 0" :flavor='cardapio.name' class="addFlavor controller-btn"> - </button>
          </div>
          <img src="img/cardapio/baska.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


data: {
    cardapios: []
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://v2-api.sheety.co/4a5e4bb41d15a6ea344152fafca024db/zunepizza/cardapio"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        let edited = response.data.cardapio;
        edited.forEach((e) => {
          e.counter = 0;
        });
        this.cardapios = edited;
      })
      .catch((error) => {})
      .finally(() => {});
  },
  methods: {}
```

Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I started to understand and use the v-model in the whole application = D